# How can I further optimize this code regarding matrix factorization?

Tags: python, matrix-factorization

I am implementing this matrix factorization code [found here](https://towardsdatascience.com/recommendation-system-matrix-factorization-d61978660b4b). How can I further optimize this code or where are the possible choke points or bottlenecks on this code(if there are any)? Thank you.

```
import numpy

def matrix_factorization(R, P, Q, K, steps=5000, alpha=0.0002, beta=0.02):
   
    Q = Q.T

    for step in range(steps):
        for i in range(len(R)):
            for j in range(len(R[i])):
                if R[i][j] > 0:
                    # calculate error
                    eij = R[i][j] - numpy.dot(P[i,:],Q[:,j])

                    for k in range(K):
                        # calculate gradient with a and beta parameter
                        P[i][k] = P[i][k] + alpha * (2 * eij * Q[k][j] - beta * P[i][k])
                        Q[k][j] = Q[k][j] + alpha * (2 * eij * P[i][k] - beta * Q[k][j])

        eR = numpy.dot(P,Q)

        e = 0

        for i in range(len(R)):

            for j in range(len(R[i])):

                if R[i][j] > 0:

                    e = e + pow(R[i][j] - numpy.dot(P[i,:],Q[:,j]), 2)

                    for k in range(K):

                        e = e + (beta/2) * (pow(P[i][k],2) + pow(Q[k][j],2))
        # 0.001: local minimum
        if e < 0.001:

            break

    return P, Q.T
```

Comment: Not a huge gain, but (believe it or not), I got about a 20% reduction in runtime just by cleaning up the numpy syntax:  change all of the `X[i][j]`s to `X[i, j]`

Comment: This factorization is built in in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html)